# jquery случайно поменять местами блоки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Добрый день! Необходимо поменять случайно местами div-ы, чтобы после каждой перезагрузки их порядок был разный.

структрура html примерно такая:

```
    <div class=parent">
        <div class="children" id=1></div>
        <div class="children" id=2></div>
        <div class="children" id=3></div>
        <div class="children" id=4></div>
 </div>
```

дочерних элементов может быть много.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
$(function () {
    var parent = $("#shuffle");
    var divs = parent.children();
    while (divs.length) {
        parent.append(divs.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length), 1)[0]);
    }
});
```

```css
#shuffle > div {
    float: left;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: steelblue;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: 3px;
}
#shuffle {
    max-width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="shuffle">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>13</div>
    <div>14</div>
    <div>15</div>
    <div>16</div>
    <div>17</div>
    <div>18</div>
    <div>19</div>
    <div>20</div>
    <div>21</div>
    <div>22</div>
    <div>23</div>
    <div>24</div>
    <div>25</div>
    <div>26</div>
    <div>27</div>
    <div>28</div>
    <div>29</div>
    <div>30</div>
    <div>31</div>
    <div>32</div>
    <div>33</div>
    <div>34</div>
    <div>35</div>
    <div>36</div>
    <div>37</div>
    <div>38</div>
    <div>39</div>
    <div>40</div>
    <div>41</div>
    <div>42</div>
    <div>43</div>
    <div>44</div>
    <div>45</div>
    <div>46</div>
    <div>47</div>
    <div>48</div>
    <div>49</div>
    <div>50</div>
    <div>51</div>
    <div>52</div>
    <div>53</div>
    <div>54</div>
    <div>55</div>
    <div>56</div>
    <div>57</div>
    <div>58</div>
    <div>59</div>
    <div>60</div>
    <div>61</div>
    <div>62</div>
    <div>63</div>
    <div>64</div>
    <div>65</div>
    <div>66</div>
    <div>67</div>
    <div>68</div>
    <div>69</div>
    <div>70</div>
    <div>71</div>
    <div>72</div>
    <div>73</div>
    <div>74</div>
    <div>75</div>
    <div>76</div>
    <div>77</div>
    <div>78</div>
    <div>79</div>
    <div>80</div>
    <div>81</div>
    <div>82</div>
    <div>83</div>
    <div>84</div>
    <div>85</div>
    <div>86</div>
    <div>87</div>
    <div>88</div>
    <div>89</div>
    <div>90</div>
    <div>91</div>
    <div>92</div>
    <div>93</div>
    <div>94</div>
    <div>95</div>
    <div>96</div>
    <div>97</div>
    <div>98</div>
    <div>99</div>
    <div>100</div>
</div>
```